# asp net jquery popup dialog form in asp:formview

Tags: asp.net, jquery, dialog, popup, formview

i have following problem, i am using a popup jquery dialog with asp:formview .

the purpose of this popup is for user to enter a hyperlink which is placed then in textbox control in formview

the popup dialog div is located outside a formview just after body tag

```
    <body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family:Lucida Console;">

        <div id="dialog-form" title="sdfdfsdf" style="font-size:14px; ">
            <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="link">sdfdf</label>
                <input type="text" name="sdfsdf" id="link" size="32" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin-top:50px;" >
    <div>

        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1"

.......
  <InsertItemTemplate>
   ...
      <sometextbox ...../>
      <button id="create-user" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Create link</button>
   ...
  </InsertItemTemplate>
```

After clicking a button a popup window is shown BUT the page starts to refresh immediately
 and of course the popup is then hidden.

If I relocate the button outside the formview - the page is not refreshed, but i need it in formview..

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

add the following attribute to the button:

```
onclick="javascript: return false;"
```

Comment: great thx!! it helped!
but now i get another problem,
i want to pass the value from popup to FreeTextBox control
i use folowing code

FTB_API['FreeTextBox1'].SetHtml("link.val()");

but the code stucks on this line, it cant find Freetextbox

though if it is outside the formview - everything is fine and value is set

if i use document.getElementById('<%=FormView1.FindControl("FreeTextBox1").ClientID%>');

iit finds the control but i wonder how can i use SetHtml() method of FreeTextBox in this case..

help plz!

Comment: You have to cast the return value of getElementByID to the JavaScript FreeTextBox type.

Answer (score 0):

this behavior should not come out because it is a button not submit button.
it seems when it is inside the form view a submit action is attached to it, check your jQuery scripts maybe you mistakenly added onclick submit while attaching the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer:

`clientId` must be used:

```
FTB_API['<%=FormView1.FindControl("AdminCommentTextBox").ClientID%>'].SetHtml(...)
```